# Which is best: to light up 'with,' 'from,' or 'off'?

Tags: word-choice, expressions, prepositions

I am trying to write a sentence that conveys the idea of lighting something up (a cigar, cigarette) using the flame of a candle. What is the correct form?

- to light up with a candle
- to light up from a candle
- to light up off a candle

Thank you for your help

Best regards

Comment: You missed out at least [*He lit up **using** a (match, blowtorch, whatever)](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+lit+up+using%22)*. And possibly other terms. All the above prepositions "work", but ***with*** is probably the most common one.

Comment: Thanks FumbleFingers. I don't want to use "using" as it were. I agree that "with" is probably the way to go. Again, thanks.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I am an inveterate smoker. I might use 'with' if I picked the candle up and lit a cigarette with it, and 'from', if, cigarette in mouth, I leaned over the candle and introduced the end of the cigarette to the flame.

Comment: Where I'm from, we might use "light up off," as in, "May I light up off your joint?" I think that works for a candle-to-cigar transaction too. Borrow something already burning to start a new fire...

Answer (score 2):

- I light candles every day. [transitive verb]
- A candle can light up a small space.
- If you light many candles, they can light up a space.

**light up** in those two examples is a **phrasal verb** and transitive.

- He lit up [a cigar or cigarette] and sat back in the armchair.

There, it is a transitive verb with the object omitted, which is an idiomatic usage.

- The little boy's face **lit up** with joy when he saw the huge ice cream on the table.

That one is figurative and stative.

Answer (score 1):

Prepositions are fun, and confusing in English -- and usually not a binary choice.

In this case, the preposition "up" is not necessary. You can *light* something without *lighting up*.

As to whether you light from, with, by, and so on, here's another choice:

*He leaned over to light his cigarette in the candle flame.*

Here's all the choices I could think of; they all would make sense in my opinion to a native speaker:

He lit the cigarette in/from/with/using/within/inside/over/by/on the candle flame.

Comment: light up and light are not the same at all.

Answer (score 0):

In English, "light up" is a two-word verb, also called a "phrasal verb."  That means that "up" in this context is not particularly acting as a preposition--it is part of the verb itself.

Furthermore, "light up" and "light" have different meanings.  To "light up" may imply an emotional outcome, e.g.

- "She lit up with joy when she heard the good news."

Or it can refer to light more generally:

- "The Christmas lights lit up the tree with colorful warmth in the darkness."

When one is lighting up a cigarette, it means simply to *ignite*.  Usage would be similar.  For example:

- "He lit up his cigarette in the flame of a candle."
- "He lit up his cigarette by the flame of a candle."
- "He lit up his cigarette using the flame of a candle."
- "He lit up his cigarette with the flame of a candle."

Beware of ambiguity.  The following sentence leaves it unclear what or whom is being "lit up" (back to "light up" being a potential reference to joy, as well as to ignite).

- "He lit up with the flame of a candle."

Was he made happy by the candle's flame?  Did the candle set him on fire? Did he light a cigar or cigarette from the candle?  Given only this sentence, a reader would be left to infer the correct meaning.

Comment: True -- people usually don't say "lit up" or "light up" in regard to cigarettes; they say "I lit my cigarette" or "I need to light my cigarette" without "up." Adding "up" almost makes it sound like shining a light on the cigarette.